# JMeter NaN issue in reports

Tags: jmeter

I have used jmeter 2.5 and ANT 1.8.2 and jdk 1.6. Also, I have used latest .xsl file path in build.xml.

Issue is iam getting NaN value for Min, Max in html reports.

Please let me know any solutions.

Comment: Are the jtl files populated with data for those values?

Comment: yes it is .i found that it is working in xp ,iam using 7!

Answer (score 2):

This problem is encountered in newer versions of Java.

I faced the same problem and this solution worked for me - Copy xalan-2.7.1.jar and serializer-2.7.1.jar from the apache-jmeter/lib folder and include it in apache-ant/lib folder of ant.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow it's a problem related to newer Java versions: If you use Java 1.5 or higher it wont work out of the box, unless you:

1. Use the build file: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/extras/build.xml
2. Include xalan.jar and serializer.jar both in jmeter lib directory

There are [two](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51906) [bugs](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51907) in apache bugzilla regarding this issue. More info:

- http://vishnuagrawal.blogspot.com/2009/04/jmeter-run-tests-using-ant.html
- http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/Min-and-Max-times-are-returning-NaN-td525870.html

Answer (score 0):

Given it works in XP and not windows 7, try running in either:

- As Administrator
- Compatibility mode