# Load Test Results with JMeter - Min/Max Time gives NaN

Tags: java, maven, xslt, jmeter

In my Maven project, I transform the generated JTL file into HTML using the `xml-maven-plugin` with Java 1.7.

Unfortunately, the Min Time and Max Time values are viewed as `NaN` :

[image: html output]

As I tried to do this manually, with excel ([like this](https://blazemeter.com/blog/visualize-jmeter-jtl-files-viewed-xsl-stylesheet)), the output is correct.

Now... I found [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579189/jmeter-nan-issue-in-reports), but including jars and using the build.xml doesn't work for me.
Does anybody know, what could be the reason for this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you move to other ways of generating results:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/automatically-generating-nice-graphs-at-end-of-your-load-test-with-apache-jmeter-and-jmeter-plugins/
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html
- https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/01/automating-jmeter-tests-Maven-jenkins/
- Or use nightly build and test this upcoming feature in next JMeter version as per :

  - http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/Donation-of-a-New-Dashboard-for-JMeter-Questions-and-more-td5723379.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem when using the JMeter Ant plugin. Including the JARs in the plugin's classpath did solve the problem. How did you include the JARs? Have you tried adding them as dependencies to the xml-maven-plugin like described here: http://www.mojohaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/examples/transform-saxon.html